# Is there any power that allows one to drain PP?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm currently reading through the rules and wondering: Is there any power that allows one to absorb/drain PP of others?

For example in some other games like wod and part time gods some splats have the ability to devour one anothers soul and thus increase in power, and I'm wondering there if such a power is stated also in M&M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not permanently, at least with anything from Green Ronin. Part of the foundation of the game is that you have the powers that you have, and that the GM gives you power points as you advance.

Now, that said, there are ways to get things like it. One way is to simply make an arrangement with your GM that, when he awards power points to the group for their actions, yours are sourced from whatever you have drained from others. You probably won't get a mechanical advantage from it, since most GMs increase the power of the group more or less in lockstep, but it would fit your theme. Secondly, you could get a Variable power with the descriptor being powers that you've gained from others. You still have to spend points on it, and you're limited to the "pool" of points there, and would have to reallocate them for new powers, but it's not the worst of solutions. Thirdly, players can use Hero Points to pay for Extra Effort, said Hero Points being gained from a Complication like "Power Source - Hero gains powers by absorbing the souls of his enemies and faces prejudice and fear as a result".

You didn't specify a system, but this does hold true for both 2E and 3E.

Of course, you can probably find a 3rd-party sourcebook that allows for such things, but that's outside of the official rules of the game, and I'd argue for simply talking with your GM to see if they're willing to houserule it in.

Comment: its  3rd edition for me. sadly didnt see any 3rd edition/2nd edition tag so only could use the "normal" tag but then again the same question holds true for both versions anyway (and probalby also the answer. And....I'm the GM but when possible I try to stick to the rules so wanted to know if there is anything I'm overlooking or iif there is any workaround there.

Comment: `m-and-m-3e` and `m-and-m-2e` FWIW. If you're the GM, then just impose your own system. As mentioned above, that can simply be how your players get power points.

Comment: thanks didnt see those (as the general one  is a bit longer I expeted them to be similar).

Answer (score -1):

Use transform affliction. Change the powers to affects others only, use quirks to make the exchange permanent. Done.

Comment: I don’t believe that this would work the way the OP intended; the Affliction would be able to remove other people’s powers with a Transformed result, but it wouldn’t empower you when you use it.